# NVPTX generic memory space location in architecture

Tags: architecture, cuda, llvm, llvm-ir, ptx

In NVPTX(LLVM IR) for CUDA programs, there're identifiers for memory address space from 0 to 5 (see Table below).

[image]

I saw in the same LLVM IR program, memory addresses are identified as 'Generic' or other types as shown in pictures.

For 'Generic' (by default, there's no identifier):
[image]

For 'Shared':
[image]

My question is that, for the generic memory address space, where is the data is actually located in hardware, off-chip, on-chip memory or local registers? Can someone explain how generic type of address space is finally managed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer is quite easy: Generic address space has no hardware representation.

You can see the generic address space (AS) as a logical AS where each of the other AS are combined. 
For example: the following kernel calls and a device function which accepts a pointer.

```
__device__ void bar(int* x){
   *x = *x + 1;
}

__global__ void foo(int* x){
   __shared__ int y[1];
   bar(x); 
   bar(y);
}
```

You can pass any pointer to the function. From the language point of view it does not mater if the pointer is in AS 1 (global) or AS 3 (shared). 
In C++ (and CUDA C/C++) you don't have to specify the AS explicitly. In OpenCL < 2.0 for example you have to explicitly add a modifier to each pointer and have to provide a function `bar` which takes the specific AS pointer.

What happens in LLVM IR is, that the pointer witch is passed to the function gets casted via an `addresspacecast` instruction to the generic AS. 
In PTX `addresspacecast` is represented by the `cvta` instruction:

```
// convert const, global, local, or shared address to generic address
cvta.space.size  p, a;        // source address in register a
cvta.space.size  p, var;      // get generic address of var
cvta.space.size  p, var+imm;  // generic address of var+offset

// convert generic address to const, global, local, or shared address
cvta.to.space.size  p, a;

.space = { .const, .global, .local, .shared };
.size  = { .u32, .u64 };
```

Generic pointers are mapped to the global memory unless it falls within an address region reserved for the other AS. The hardware subtracts the start address of the AS from the generic pointer to determine the correct memory region.

Atomics are a good example:

```
atom{.space}.op.type  d, [a], b;
atom{.space}.op.type  d, [a], b, c;
```

You can specify an address space or let the hardware choose. If you want to generate the correct atomic instruction without the pointer subtraction overhead, the back-end is responsible for casting the pointer back to the correct address space.

Comment: So based on your answer, you are saying that if a pointer is in AS1 in LLVM IR, we have no way to know whether it will go to global or shared etc. memory, right?

Comment: If the pointer is in AS1 we know it is in global memory. If it is in AS0 then only the hardware knows it for sure. See AS0 as concatination oft all AS from  1 to 5.